# How to use auto increment in sails-mongo

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I was just playing around the concepts of sailsjs then I came to know we cannot use auto increments in sails if we are using mongodb as our database. I cannot able to use the auto increments even for the non primary key attributes. Is there any special methods to use auto increments operations for an attribute which is not a primary key? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If waterline doesn't support it automatically, which is what it seems like, you can do it in the `beforeCreate` [lifecycle callback](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) of waterline. It is independent of any database adapter.

I would recommend you to take a look at how lifecycle callbacks work for clear understanding. Workflow would be something like following. Before creating any record you would check the count of records of the `Model`. Then update the `x` field of the records to be created as one more than that found count and pass the batton.

```
beforeCreate: function(obj, next){
    Model.count().exec(function(err, cnt){
        if(err) next(err);
        else{
            obj['x'] = cnt + 1;
            next(null);
        }
    })
}
```

Counting the records is not the perfect way. You can change the way you like to find the value of auto-incremented value. Purpose of this example is to give you intuition of how it can be done. This is not the exact alternative of autoincrement but it's an effective workaround I guess. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Cool solving manner! Something weird but it works and solve the problem easily! Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `Model` var ?

Comment: While the beforeCreate recommendation is sound, using the count() method is not, because (a) the values of obj['x'] may not coincide with the count, (b) if records get deleted the values will be thrown off and all records need to be updated to be accurate. Better method: Do a find() and sort the results based on an integer column, pick the first result, then increment that!

Comment: The only safe way to use auto increment with mongodb is to have a counter collection where you store other collections auto increment index.

Answer (score 7):

There are different strategies, how you can create auto increment sequences with mongo. You can find the general information in the official documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Here is an adaptation of the first approach for sails.js waterline, which uses counter collection. First you have to create a Sequence Model and implement a get next method.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes : {
        num : {
            type : "integer"
        },
    },

    next : function (id, cb) {

        Sequence.native(function (err, col) {

            col.findAndModify(
                { _id: id },
                [['_id', 'asc']],
                {$inc: { num : 1 }},
                { new: true, upsert : true}
                , function(err, data) {

                    cb(err, data.value.num);
                });

        });

    },
};
```

Since waterline doesn't support findAndModify functionality of mongodb, you have to make use of native driver method. It looks bit weird, but it works. More about it [here](http://www.yarni.net/2015/06/findandmodify-mongoerror-need-remove-or.html).

And then you can just call the Sequence.next() in the beforeCreate lifecycle callback method of your model to get next auto increment value for the new collection document.

```
// Model Order, for Example.
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        number: {
            type: "integer"
        },
        // other attributes
    },

    // add auto increment value for "number" before create a document
    beforeCreate : function (values, cb) {

        // add seq number, use
        Sequence.next("order", function(err, num) {

            if (err) return cb(err);

            values.number = num;

            cb();
        });
    }

    // your other methods ...
};
```

I know it is a bit late, but I just solved it for me and wanted to share.

Comment: Where is the `Sequence` var ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works with Sails v1

```js
// api/models/Sequence.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    num: { type: 'number' }
  },
  next (id, cb) {
    var db = Sequence.getDatastore().manager
    var collection = db.collection('num')

    collection.findAndModify(
      { _id: id },
      [[ '_id', 'asc' ]],
      { $inc: { num : 1 }},
      { new: true, upsert : true },
      (err, data) => cb(err, data.value.num)
    )
  }
}
```

```js
// api/models/Order.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    number: { type: 'number' },
  },
  beforeCreate (obj, cb) {
    Sequence.next('order', (err, num) => {
      if (err) return cb(err)
      obj.number = num
      cb()
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in the implementation with Native in Sails, here it's a working sample. The sample assumes that you have a Counters collection:

```
Counters.native(function(err, collection) {

        collection.findAndModify(
          {"_id": "order_id"}, // query
          [['_id','asc']],  // sort order
          { "$inc": { "seq": 1 }}, // increments the seq
          {"new": true}, // options
          function(err, object) {
              if (err){
                  sails.log.debug("ERROR",err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
              }else{
                  sails.log.debug(object);
              }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Where would this code go? In a hook to modify the database?

Comment: I put this code inside a function in a Service. The service can then be accessed from  everywhere you need